# How to cover the missing branch from time delay condition in JUnit

Tags: java, xml, junit

would like to ask for help regarding unit testing my method which sets a time delay.  I was only able to cover the half of this method.  Here is the method

```
public void setDelay() {
    XMLHandler objXMLHdl = new XMLHandler();
    
    String delay = objXMLHdl.GetXMLValue("myConfig.xml", "/config/WS/delay");
    String intDelay = objXMLHdl.GetXMLValue("myConfig.xml", "/config/WS/delay_minutes");
    
    if (delay.equals("1")) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(Integer.parseInt(intDelay));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the test

```
public class WSGlobalFunctionsTest {

WSGlobalsFunctions globalFunction = new WSGlobalsFunctions();
XMLHandler objXMLHdl = new XMLHandler();



@Test
public void testSetDelay() { 
    globalFunction.setDelay();
}

@Test
public void testSetDelayFailed() throws NumberFormatException, InterruptedException, JAXBException {
    
    String delay = objXMLHdl.GetXMLValue("myConfig.xml", "/config/WS/delay");
    String intDelay = objXMLHdl.GetXMLValue("myConfig.xml", "/config/WS/delay_minutes");
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(Integer.parseInt(intDelay));
    globalFunction.setDelay();
    
}
```

Here is the XML file

```
<config>
<WS>
    <delay>0</delay>
    <delay_minutes>2</delay_minutes>        
</WS>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. T

Comment: All your first test does is check that setDelay() doesn't throw an exception. What is your second test trying to test?

Answer (score 0):

I'd restructure your code something like this:

```
interface Sleeper {
  void sleep(int minutes);
}

class Delay {
  public Delay(XmlHandler objXMLHdl, Sleeper sleeper) {
  ...
  }

  public void doDelay() {
    String delay = objXMLHdl.GetXMLValue("myConfig.xml", "/config/WS/delay");
    String intDelay = objXMLHdl.GetXMLValue("myConfig.xml", "/config/WS/delay_minutes");
    
    if (delay.equals("1")) {
         sleeper.sleep(Integer.parseInt(intDelay));
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can mock `XmlHandler` and `Sleeper` and test your `Delay` class properly, without your test needing to actually take minutes to run.

You can have a test of normal behaviour where you check that sleep() was called with the correct number of minutes, a case where delay is "0" where you check that sleep() isn't called, and a case where you pass an non-numeric string for intDelay which should throw a NumberFormatException.

You can make your code more testable without changing the interface your clients currently use. Assuming you aren't using any dependency injection framework:

```
class WSGlobalFunctions {
...
  private Delay delay = new Delay(new XmlHandler(), new Sleeper());
...
  public void setDelay() {
    delay.doDelay();
  }
...
}
```

`setDelay` is now trivial so you don't need to test it.

Comment: will it cover the missing branch of  ` if (delay.equals("1")) ` if i will throw an exception on the secong test method ` @Test
public void testSetDelayFailed()  ` ?

Sorry, I cannot changed the structure of my code. Thanks.

Comment: @Ronald I've illustrated how to make your code testable and retain the previous usage patterns.